# How to return the value of a hidden input using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the value of a hidden input.

my current hidden looks like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="extend_1" id="extend_1" value="16:00:00">
```

so I try to get that value when $('time') is changed

so I have this code in my page but the value is always undefined! I am using jQuery 1.9

```
$('time').change( function(){
        var this_id = "extend_" + $(this).val();
//if i alert this_id i not get "extend_1" howeven max_time is always returning undefined where it should display "16:00:00"
        var max_time = $( this_id ).val();
        console.log( max_time )
});
```

Can anybody please tell me what is wrong? why is max_time is always undefined?

Thanks

Comment: most likely because you wrote "extend_" instead of "#extend_", but you really haven't posted enough code for me to say for sure.

Comment: OK, now I'm sure; posted an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the hash in your jQuery string. It should be `"#extend_" + $(this).val()`.

Comment: Yep, that was the answer. i know it was something silly like that.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @Mike - If that's the answer then please mark it as so.